# how to close a tabbar swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a login view controller which on a correct login will open a tabbar controller with the following method:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { self.loadHomeScreen()})

func loadHomeScreen()
    {
        emailField.text = ""
        passwordField.text = ""

        self.presentViewController(UIStoryboard.tabbarController()!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


private extension UIStoryboard {
        class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) }

        class func tabbarController() -> UITabBarController? {
            return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabbarControllerID") as? UITabBarController
        }
    }
```

I think my login view controller is still in the background? I have a logout button as the rightbarbutton item on each navbar in my tabgroup. I want to be able to close the tabbar on this button press. How can I achieve this. I can't find any examples. Would I be using a pop command?

**UPDATE:**

```
@IBAction func tryLogout(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("login") as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: @DharmeshKheni and my tabgroup wont be in the background taking up memory?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni how to dismiss current viewController in swift?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni ok that was slightly different as I was dissmissing an activity alert. Taking your approach, my app is crashing with an unkown exception of type NSException. Updated question to show my code

Comment: @DharmeshKheni self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) is dismissing a view controller but I need to dismiss a tabbar controller. Is this the issue?